# How to print all the permutations of two lists in a custom format?

Tags: python, list, tuples, permutation

```
P = [(2, 2, 3), (2, 3, 2), (3, 2, 2)]

X = [[(1, 2, 4), (1, 4, 2), (2, 1, 4), (2, 4, 1), (4, 1, 2), (4, 2, 1)], [(1, 2, 6), (1, 6, 2), (2, 1, 6), (2, 6, 1), (6, 1, 2), (6, 2, 1)], [(1, 3, 6), (1, 6, 3), (3, 1, 6), (3, 6, 1), (6, 1, 3), (6, 3, 1)]]
```

How can I print all the permutations of the above 2 lists in the form:

```
P1(X1) P2(x2) P3(x3)
```

for example:

```
2(1) 2(2) 3(4),
2(1) 2(4) 3(2),
2(2) 2(1) 3(4) and so on
```

i.e. first tuple from P combines with all tuples of X then second tuple of P combines with all tuples of X and so on.

Comment: `2(1) 2(2) 3(4)` is this a string?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) and [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) this way:

```
from itertools import product

P = [(2, 2, 3), (2, 3, 2), (3, 2, 2)]

X = [[(1, 2, 4), (1, 4, 2), (2, 1, 4), (2, 4, 1), (4, 1, 2), (4, 2, 1)],
     [(1, 2, 6), (1, 6, 2), (2, 1, 6), (2, 6, 1), (6, 1, 2), (6, 2, 1)],
     [(1, 3, 6), (1, 6, 3), (3, 1, 6), (3, 6, 1), (6, 1, 3), (6, 3, 1)]]

for p, xs in product(P, X):
    for x in xs:
        print(" ".join(f"{a}({b})" for a, b in zip(p, x)))
```

this outputs

```
2(1) 2(2) 3(4)
2(1) 2(4) 3(2)
2(2) 2(1) 3(4)
2(2) 2(4) 3(1)
2(4) 2(1) 3(2)
2(4) 2(2) 3(1)
2(1) 2(2) 3(6)
2(1) 2(6) 3(2)
2(2) 2(1) 3(6)
...
```